# How to use dart shelf_router in web only dart project

Tags: dart

From the example given at this place :
https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_router/example
I have written the router part like this :

```
class Service {
  Handler get handler {
    final router = Router();
    router.get('/say-hi/<name>', (Request request, String name) {
      return Response.ok('hi $name');
    });
    router.get('/user/<userId|[0-9]+>', (Request request, String userId) {
      return Response.ok('User has the user-number: $userId');
    });
    router.get('/wave', (Request request) async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      return Response.ok('_o/');
    });
    router.mount('/api/', Api().router);
    router.all('/<ignored|.*>', (Request request) {
      return Response.notFound('Page not found');
    });
    return router;
  }
}
class Api {
  Future<Response> _messages(Request request) async {
    return Response.ok('[]');
  }
    Router get router {
    final router = Router();
    router.get('/messages', _messages);
    router.get('/messages/', _messages);
uter.all('/<ignored|.*>', (Request request) => Response.notFound('null'));
    return router;
  }
}
```

and from the main method it tells to use it like this:

```
void main() async {
  final service = Service();
  final server = await shelf_io.serve(service.handler, 'localhost', 8080);
  print('Server running on localhost:${server.port}');
}
```

but in web-only project we don't do : final server = await shelf_io.serve(service.handler, 'localhost', 8080);

I was thinking of creating single page application using a shelf router, I saw from the documentation it says that it is compatible with the dart web js platform

My expectation was :
if I write this in web :

```
router.get('/say-hi/<name>', (Request request, String name) {
  return Response.ok('hi $name');
});
```

then when I will hit /say-hi/ram, then it should have returned "hi ram" in the browser

Comment: AFAIK shelf is meant for server applications, not single page web-apps. As you point out, in a single page webapp you don't create a local server.

Comment: but the document says it is supported for web javascript, even I imported all the libs in the same dart file and started the programs and it was starting successfully